# Recoverable error while creating user

Tags: magento2

Hi am trying to create a user in magento 2 by taking custom password fields from the the checkout form

but am getting below error

**1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Recoverable Error: Object of class Ntz\CaptureShipping\Observer\Convertguest could not be converted to string in E:\xampp\htdocs\m2dev\app\code\Ntz\CaptureShipping\Observer\Convertguest.php on line 62**

**line 62**

```
$customer->$this->_checkoutSession->getPassword();
$customer->$this->_checkoutSession->getConfirmPassword();
```

However the order is placed successfully then this observer throws an error

Comment: are you able to tell which line is your line 62 and you cropped the top of your file?

Comment: check the updated questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace these lines:

```
$customer->$this->_checkoutSession->getPassword();
$customer->$this->_checkoutSession->getConfirmPassword();
```

by

```
$customer->setPassword($this->_checkoutSession->getPassword());
$customer->setConfirmPassword($this->_checkoutSession->getConfirmPassword());
```

easy done, the last update is likely better for you though.

Comment: oo god lol thankss

Comment: already figured this out this will save 2 lines dude

Comment: this updated ans has the same exact error previous one was better how ever it throws another error but fix this one

Comment: did you change these 2 lines, not sure where you are now?